# User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: freebase

As I am not coming close to 100000 queries per day I am assuming that Google is referring to the Freebase 10 requests per second per user limit. (I am passing in my Goggle Key)

If i am running a query that crosses multiple Freebase domains is that considered more than one request? Or is a single query considered one request regardless of it size?

thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds like you're exceeding the per/second rate limit. You'll need to introduce some delays in your application so that you don't exceed the limit. The rate limit only applies to HTTP requests so you can query as much data as you like as long as it fits in one request.